# How would I re-use these functions instead of having one per textfield?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I'm learning spfx using SPO.
I have a form which has several text fields. I have 2 class components. (A and B) Each time a textfield on (B) is typed into, a function sends the return to a props file. (This is called Lifting State up I believe). These props are then used by a handler function in (A) so whatever is typed can be submitted to an SP list by (A). This all works fine. But I've noticed that I'm creating functions for each and every textfield. Can someone tell me a way to re-use a function.
Here's one of the functions from (B):

```
private _onJobTitleChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
    this.setState({
      JobTitle: newValue
    });
  }
```

Here's a handler function from (A):

```
private _onJobTitleChange = (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, newValue?: string) => {
    this.setState({
      JobTitle: newValue
    });
  }
```

As you can see the handler function sets the state so it can be submitted to the list.

If you need it here's the props file:

```
export interface IEvalReqNewProps {
  context: WebPartContext;
  description: string;
  jobTitleReportTo: string;
  onJobTitleReportToChange(value: string ): void;
  jobTitleReportToNum: string;
  onJobTitleReportToNumChange(value: string ): void;
  propGradeChange: string;
  onPropGradeChange(value: IDropdownOption): void;
  compPosTit1: string;
  onCompPostTit1Change(value: string ): void;
  compPosTit2: string;
  onCompPostTit2Change(value: string ): void;
  compPosTit3: string;
  onCompPostTit3Change(value: string ): void;
```

You can see I'm creating multiple function for these fields and it's getting messy. I'd appreciate a code example instead of a description of what to do. Thanks v much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can handle it like this:

```
public handleMultipleFields = (field: string, value: string) => {
    const { foo } = this.state;
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
  };
```

[ReactJS Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs)

Another example if you have to update certain object in state:

```
public handleObjectWithMultipleFields = (field: string, value: string) => {
    const { myObject } = this.state;
    this.setState({ myObject: { ...myObject, [field]: value } });
  };
```

Comment: Can you give me an example with my code examples above? I'm struggling with that answer.

Comment: I've set your response as an answer but would like bit more of an explanation if possible?